# help to find a taboo equivalent

Tags: phrases, idioms, offensive-language

Excuse me for what you are going to read now.
If you don't accept the taboo lexics, please don't read this.

There is a taboo phrase in Russian: "ебись оно всё конём" /jebis ono vsjo konjom/ which means that the speaker doesn't care absolutely of the matter of the discussion or can't do anything with curcumstances and gives up.
In that taboo phrase figures a sexual process in imperative mood /ебись - jebis/, the word combination /оно всё - ono vsjo/ meaning 'everything, all this matter' and a horse /конём -  konjom/ as the instrument of the action.

The history of that phrase, they say is from chess. because the horse in the game is very tricky, or because the angry player could throw it into the face of another player. The others say it is from the horse races.

So, my question is: is there in English anything with this meaning, equally rude and funny?

I need as many taboo equivalents of the described expression as possible.

Comment: As a native Russian speaker, I'm almost positive that "ебись оно всё конём" refers to the speaker not caring if "оно"  gets (literally) fucked by a horse, which, as one can imagine, could be quite painful, unpleasant and devastating. The chess and races explanations are way off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've read properly between the lines, your Russian phrase translates as

> Fuck everything and the horse as well.

We do have a (rough) equivalent in English:

> Fuck you and the horse you rode in on.

Let's go to the [videotape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ld2oR_G9Zw).

Comment: My thoughts, almost. But didn't think SE would let me post such an answer.

Comment: @NVZ The discussion of offensive language is allowed, because this is a language site. Gratuitous use of offensive language is frowned upon (and acted upon).

Comment: @deadrat in your example the process of 'fucking' is aplied to the audiense AND to the horse. The Russian phrase showes THE HORSE as the let's say the instrument which "everyting" must use to go to hell.
your equivalent does not fit well, but it is funny.

Comment: @NVZ I'd like to see your examples, please